# How can i get the contact list starting from and alphabet written on a button clicked in android?

Tags: android

I am using this code in my application to display the whole contact list , now i want to parse the contact list like - if i am pressing the button with text "A", it should display the contacts starting from alphabet "A". Is there any way to change the query for this purpose?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
                            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                                Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                    }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at it, might help you: http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your query like this

```
Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE " + yourText +"%";
```

You can include where condition as the last param

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Firstly get Text from button

```
 Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
```

and do as following

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONCERNEDCOLUMN LIKE 'a%';//here starts with 'a'
```

So you need to change the query such that

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONCERNEDCOLUMN LIKE '"+buttonText+"%'";
```

P.S: Just take idea from the above, don't just copy paste. The **query** string might have error too. Then use the query as rawQuery.

```
db.rawQuery(query, null);// may be return this
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how to use the above query in android application code?

Comment: @user2542088 ask if some problem in above answer